# CSS Image referencing for Dev to Test

Tags: css, image-processing

I have some images that are used in the css file. This works great in my dev solution, but when I move it over to Test, the images don't work. This is due to "test" being added in the url,

so it looks like.... localhost/**test**/home.aspx

It's this "test" that is causing the problem. my images are referenced like so in the css file:

```
../img/ui-darkness/images/ui-bg_glass_45_0078ae_1x400.png
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what i can use that will allow my solution to use the images when moving to different domains?

Cheers

Comment: Where is the images folder and where is the css folder?

For example: `localhost/test/css/` and `localhost/test/img/`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to setup your directory structures within your project to be consistent on your local machine, your dev environment and your production environment.  The more each environment mimics the other the better testing you can perform.

Answer (score 0):

think for now uhave css like this:

```
.somediv {
  background-image: url(/test/images/img1.png);
}
```

you need to update css to read image url's as :

```
.somediv {
  background-image: url(images/img1.png);
}
```

or if the public folder in some other place, as example:

```
/test
--/public
----/images
----/css
```

then try this:

```
.somediv {
  background-image: url(../images/img1.png);
}
```

**EDIT 1**

in other words you need to make **relative** url instead of `/root/werwer/qwerwer/images`